# How to find vertices of a polytope in python?

Tags: python, enumeration, vertex

I want to find the vertices given the following:

```
   `A = np.array([
               [-1,2/3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [1,-2/3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [-1,0,0,2/3,0,0,0,0,0],
               [-1,0,2/3,0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [1,0,-2/3,0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [-1,0,0,0,2/3,0,0,0,0],
               [-1,0,0,0,2/3,0,0,0,0],
               [1,0,0,-2/3,0,0,0,0,0],
               [-1,2/3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])`
    `b = np.array([-1/3, 1/3, -2/3, 1/3, -1/3, 0, -2/3, 2/3, -1/3])` .
```

I tried to compute the vertices by using the
`vertices = pypoman.compute_polytope_vertices(A,b)`.
However, I get the following error:

> raise Exception("Polyhedron is not a polytope")
> Exception: Polyhedron is not a polytope".

Did anyone have a problem like this?

Answer (score 1):

Use **pycddlib**:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
import cdd as pcdd
import fractions as frac

A = np.array([
               [-1,frac.Fraction(2,3),0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [1,-frac.Fraction(2,3),0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [-1,0,0,frac.Fraction(2,3),0,0,0,0,0],
               [-1,0,frac.Fraction(2,3),0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [1,0,-frac.Fraction(2,3),0,0,0,0,0,0],
               [-1,0,0,0,frac.Fraction(2,3),0,0,0,0],
               [-1,0,0,0,frac.Fraction(2,3),0,0,0,0],
               [1,0,0,-frac.Fraction(2,3),0,0,0,0,0],
               [-1,frac.Fraction(2,3),0,0,0,0,0,0,0]])

b = np.array([
    [-frac.Fraction(1,3)], 
    [frac.Fraction(1,3)], 
    [-frac.Fraction(2,3)], 
    [frac.Fraction(1,3)], 
    [-frac.Fraction(1,3)], 
    [0], 
    [-frac.Fraction(2,3)], 
    [frac.Fraction(2,3)], 
    [-frac.Fraction(1,3)]
])

M = np.hstack( (b, -A) )

mat = pcdd.Matrix(M, linear=False, number_type="fraction") 
mat.rep_type = pcdd.RepType.INEQUALITY

poly = pcdd.Polyhedron(mat)
ext = poly.get_generators()
print(ext)
```

Giving:

```
 1 2/3 1/2 3/2 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 1 3/2 3/2 3/2 0 0 0 0 0
 0 2/3 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Indeed, this is not a polytope. A "1" in the first column means it is an extreme point, and here there is only one.